# PHP: get the browser name

Tags: php

How do I get the browser name using PHP? I thought this would be straightforward? All I need to do is differentiate between IE and Firefox.

Comment: Though it's entirely possible to get a value (as described in the answers below) for the browser, you should be aware that the value is not necessarily accurate.

Comment: **Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895727/how-can-i-detect-the-browser-with-php-or-javascript/**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '(compatible; MSIE ')!==FALSE) {
    ...ie specific...
}
```

But! **Don't!**

There is rarely a good reason to be sniffing user-agent at the server side. It brings a bunch of problems, including:

- browsers and other user-agents that lie about who they are, or strip the user-agent header completely, or generally make it hard to distinguish what the real browser is from the header text. For example the above rule will also detect Opera when it's spoofing IE, and IEMobile (Windows Mobile), which you may or may not want as it is a very different browser to desktop IE.
- if you discriminate on the user-agent at the server-side, you must return a `Vary: User-Agent` header in the response, otherwise proxies may cache a version of the page and return it to other browsers that don't match. However, including this header has the side-effect of messing up caching in IE.

Depending on what it is you are trying to achieve, there is almost always a much better way of handling the differences between IE and other browsers at the client side, using CSS hacks, JScript or [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx). What is the real purpose for trying to detect IE in your case?

Comment: Exactly. If you cURL with; `CURLOPT_USERAGENT('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17');` and poof it's spoofed :)

Answer (score 13):

Try this code...

```
<?php
function getBrowser()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
}

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'];
echo $yourbrowser;

?>
```

**Output of Firefox**

```
Mozilla Firefox
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
var_dump(get_browser(null, true));
?>
```

Prints:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

Answer (score 7):

$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Answer (score 2):

1) Accurate detector: [BrowserDetection.php](https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection/blob/master/lib/BrowserDetection.php)  ([Examples](http://wolfcast.com/open-source/browser-detection/tutorial.php))

2) primitive function :

```
function get_user_browser()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];        $ub = '';
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent))          {   $ub = "ie";     }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))   {   $ub = "firefox";    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))    {   $ub = "safari"; }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))    {   $ub = "chrome"; }
    elseif(preg_match('/Flock/i',$u_agent)) {   $ub = "flock";      }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) {   $ub = "opera";      }
    return $ub;
}
```

Comment: thanks working perfect !