# HTML Browser statement

Tags: html

I have a panel, where I'd like to have different things appear as you use different browsers, when using IE, Firefox or others. I would rather not like to make this for every browser, but only for this 3 statement.

The question is, would the following code work prefectly, or is there any other way to declare two browsers at the same time?

```
<!--[if IE]> This is IE <![endif]-->
<!--[if firefox]> This is Firefox <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE & !Firefox]> This is not IE and not Firefox, but something else. <![endif]-->
```

Comment: To me, this kind of trick should be used only as a last resort for the few but possible cases where you can't possibly create a cross-browser solution. You better should try to find another solution, possibly by exposing here the original source of the problem that lead you to this thinking... If you don't have to support older versions of IE, you should be able to do most of the things a cross-browser way...

Comment: It surely won’t work that way, since the “pseudocomment” thing is IE-only (and not present in modern IE either). As regards to browser sniffing in general, there are probably several questions with good answers at SO.

Comment: Browser detection is impossible in HTML. Using client-side JavaScript or server-side code, it is possible, with caveats, but asking for “any other way” makes the question too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the third statement. If you have already defined a special case for IE and Firefox, the following code will be executed in the remaining browsers.

But you have to consider that the code following is still executed by all browsers.

Comment: But won't that make it appear two times in Firefox and IE?

Comment: Although this isn't false, you ommit to say it will also be executed in IE and Firefox, which the OP might not want...

Comment: What you write into those <!-- Comments --> is defined as a special case which means that everything that is in there is a special setting for this browser. Whatever follows those lines and is not in comments will be executed in all remaining browsers.

Comment: Yes. Bartude is right. Those Comments are not only a special case, they are also an addition to what follows. In this case you would like to try to put all your code into those three comments, right?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there are no official *conditional comments* for Firefox.

### Possibility #1 - JavaScript

What could be done is using JavaScript to check the browser agent.
**Warning:** The browser agent can easily be spoofed.

**JavaScript**

```
function getBrowser()
{
  var browser = navigator.userAgent;
  if (browser.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1) return 'ie';
  else if (browser.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) return 'firefox';
  else return 'mozilla';
}

var browser = getBrowser();

if(browser == "ie"){
  /* IE code */
}

if(browser == "firefox"){
  /* Firefox code */
}

if(browser == "mozilla"){
  /* Other browsers */
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc. */
}
```

---

### Possibility #2 - CSS/JavaScript (uses a plugin)

Although this isn't the most optimized way, here is an idea that you could use:

- Insert this plugin within your page: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/.
- Write all the necessary HTML code within different `div` elements, each with a specific **ID** attribute and all hidden by default (`display:none;` in CSS).
- Use JavaScript to check what color the box is. Depending on the color, show the right `div` element. You can also remove the hidden `div` elements.
- hide the CSS plugin box or remove it from the DOM.

---

### Possibility #3 - PHP

Don't think about it. This is a bad practice. You can read why, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199793/php-get-the-browser-name).

---

I will add more possibilities as they come to my mind. This is a wiki everyone, feel free to add your 2 cents !