# Check Browser PHP and put results in .txt

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect the browser with PHP or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895727/how-can-i-detect-the-browser-with-php-or-javascript)

I want to check what browser visitors to my site are using, and then save the results to a file named browser.txt on my server. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try Google. Lots of examples out there.

Comment: See: [HTTP_USER_AGENT](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: What do You want to have in browser.txt? Well, You may have a nice access logs already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just install [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) which does that (and an awful lot more) for you (albeit it doesn't store the data on your server)? Alternatively you could just check your server logs, the data should also be in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents(
    __DIR__ . '/browser.txt',
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    FILE_APPEND
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do this:

```
get_browser( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

it will return an object/array containing all the information you need.
thake a look at [PHP get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)