# How to detect browser?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect the browser with PHP or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895727/how-can-i-detect-the-browser-with-php-or-javascript)

I need to show different information in different browser ( Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera ). So I need a way to detect the user's browser.
What is the best way to do that in my case ?

I could use PHP or Javascript but I want to avoid to use external library like jQuery.

Thanks :)

Comment: [Search first, please.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+detect+browser)

Comment: important question - why? you should be able to serve the same site to ANY browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Browser detection* is a really unreliable practice, and should be avoided. That being said, you typically get started by *sniffing* `navigator.userAgent` in JavaScript, or checking the userAgent (or [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)) as it comes across with the requests to your server.

However, don't do this - please (for the ponies). Use feature detection instead. Tools like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) make it very easy for you to deliver content up only when it's supported, and to code around differences between browsers.

Comment: why is a unreliable practice ? Many sites do that.

Comment: @xRobot Because the user agent string is not immutable, it can be changed. Additionally, user agent strings are *constantly* changing, from one version to another. You even have browsers posing as other browsers to get around silly obstacles put in place by some developers. Plugins in a browser can also modify the user agent string.

Comment: Ok thanks but I need to do it. In your opinion, how pinterest do that: https://pinterest.com/about/goodies/

Comment: @xRobot I sincerely doubt that you *need* to do it, and I assure you that it *will* cause you some sanity-loss in the future most likely. You can use `get_browser()` to determine *potential* truths about the users browser.

Comment: I have to do something like Pinterest ( different istructions for different browsers ), so how would you do that ?

Comment: @xRobot Use [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). It returns an array, check `$array['browser']`.

Comment: "different instructions for different browsers" what's wrong with: writing the instructions for the users " if you are using bower XXX do this, if you are using "YYY" do this" ?????

Comment: @xRobot I would show instructions for *all* browsers, but shuffle the browser you *think* they're using to the top of the list.

Comment: @Dagon Too much istructions in 1 page and many users don't know what browser they are using. So I need to do this as simplest as possible.

Comment: @xRobot Just understand that you may tell somebody in IE10 how to install in IE6, or somebody in Chrome how to install in Firefox. User Agent strings *aren't* reliable..

Comment: What do you think about this library: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html ?

Comment: @xRobot Note how it has a fixed data set of various browsers. Where is Maxthon on this list? It's not there. And what happens when another vendor pops up? You will be alienating users.

Comment: not listening\reading are you, why do you bother asking, all the best.

Comment: I am interested only in the most used browser ( ie, firefox, safari, chrome and opera ). I never heard about maxthon.

Comment: which is the whole point. what's most used today may well not exist next week. Netscape was the most use at one time.

Comment: @xRobot This is exactly the problem with browser-sniffing. Maxthon happens to beat Chrome in many HTML compat tests - but you didn't know that, ergo, you wouldn't sniff it out in the user's request. In 5 years, when there's a new big player, will you return to your code and write all new tests again?

Comment: Yep, I will return to my code every month.

Comment: @xRobot With all due respect, that still doesn't make *browser sniffing* a reliable practice. Not only will you have to return to your code, you'll have to keep a running tab on all new browsers, their varying user agent strings, re-download the browscap.ini for server-side testing, and more. It's an unsustainable means to an end.

Comment: I know but I think that this is the best solution: I can't insert all istructions in 1 page and allow the user to follow the correct istruction for the correct browser ( most users are ignorant and they don't know what a browser mean ).

Comment: @xRobot As I said, you *can* put instructions for all browsers in one file. Use an accordion to collapse instructions for other browsers. Place the browser you *think* they're using at the top, and have it expanded and viewable by default. Include images of the browsers so they can visually identify their if they need to.

Comment: Great, then I will do this :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

*php*

```
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
if (preg_match("/MSIE/i",$agent)) { echo "its ie!"; }
```

*javascript*

```
navigator.appName
navigator.appVersion
```

you can combine/crosscheck and starting to make a large if/else chunk
with everything you find.

also check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)
but i agree, this is non 100% reliable