# Check what kind of browser the user is using

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have a website with a few jQuery animations, commands, etc.
It runs flawlessly in Google Chrome and Firefox, but is a real pain when it comes to IE.

Is there a code I can insert at the beginning of my webpage (before loading anything else) in order to check what browser the user is using, and if it's IE, get a warning box to pop up to ask him (kindly) to consider switching to FIrefox or Chrome?

**INFO**: I have no knowledge whatsoever in .NET, PHP, or other server-side languages (didn't really need it so far).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect the browser with PHP or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895727/how-can-i-detect-the-browser-with-php-or-javascript)

Comment: There are many many solutions to common cross-broswer issues. Advising user to use another browser should be the very last resort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect IE version in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use the IE-only IF commands (other browser treat them as comments)?:

`<!--[if IE]><div id="ie-warning">Please switch browsers!</div><![endif]-->` No JS needed

For versions:

`<!--[if IE lte 7]>Your IE is version 7 or lower<![endif]-->` (IE Less Than or Equal to 7)
`<!--[if IE gte 8]>Your IE is version 8 or higher<![endif]-->` (IE Greater Than or Equal to 8)

Sorry if I'm missing something, but I think that will work.

Further info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Boom! right there!! cheers! ;)
Any way to completely stop loading the page if it is indeed IE?? (just stop at that gray page saying "please switch browsers"?

Comment: in your head: `<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=ie-warning-page.html">
<style type="text/css">body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td { display: none; } </style><![endif]-->`

Comment: First bit redirects the page to an IE warning page, second bit hides everything to make sure they don't get a flash of any content.

Comment: @BDdL Forgot to at-mention your name yesterday when I posted that so will do now to make sure you see the comment.

Comment: ^^ I know this was ages ago, but for Googlers that found themeslves here: All you need to hide the page and redirect them is: `<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=ie-warning-page.html"><style type="text/css">body{ display:none; } </style><![endif]-->`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

I have used this is some of my webpages/sites...

```
if (!$.browser.mozilla || jQuery.browser.msie) {

// do something....


}
```

Comment: "The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3"

Comment: Really? I've been using it with 1.7.2... I best have a look at my apps/websites, you've got me worried

Comment: It hasn't been removed from the core jQuery yet.

Comment: It's still there, but as the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) says, `jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.` And it's in deprecated list too, http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery.browser property

refer link

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, you can use it to detect the browser while implementing [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/):

Browser info:

```
<script>
jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
  $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>").appendTo( document.body );
});
</script>
```

(example taken from [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/))

Comment: a'ight, i see the main picture, although i am not very very proficient in jQuery.
I basically insert that as the first script in my <head> tag, and it checks it?
how do i add the popping message box that asks them to change their (stupid) browser if it is indeed IE?*

Comment: Basically yes... but its not the best style, it is merely to demonstrate how it works. You might wanna delve a bit deeper into the usage of jQuery. There is a great post on how to create popup messages with jQuere here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It's no nice solution but you could set a variable like `isIE = true` with conditional comments.