# HTML - How to show different image in different user agents?

Tags: javascript, html, user-agent

If I use Chrome I want to show img1.jpg (`<img src="img1.jpg" alt="my Chrome Image">`). Otherwise, if I use IE, I want to show img2.jpg (`<img src="img2.jpg" alt="my IE Image">`). Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is. http://jsfiddle.net/1s22amge/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check what kind of browser the user is using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978940/check-what-kind-of-browser-the-user-is-using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match = navigator.userAgent.match(/(chrome|safari|firefox|msie|opera|rv:11)\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i);
```

**match[1]** gives browser name. Also **"rv:11"** represents IE11.

For example, you can prepare prefixed images and use matched value as prefix:

```
myImg.src=match[1]+"-img1.jpg";
myImg.alt=match[1]+" Image";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the below function and then just use the IF statements to set the attribute for that image.

```
function browsercheck() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    return (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !! userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./));

}

var browser = browsercheck() ? 'IE' : 'Chrome';

if (browser == "IE")
{
     //Set attribute   
}

else if (browser == "Chrome")
{
     //Set attribute   
}
```

**Use the below if you need to know exact browser**

```
navigator.browsercheck= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem,
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return { 'browser': M[0], 'version': M[1] };
})();
```

You can then query this with `navigator.browserInfo.browser` to get browser info or `navigator.browserInfo.version` if you need to know the exact version.

Credit: [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: See edit for grabbing exact browser info. Looks like they were after Chrome or IE, but for the exact version they can tie in the added code